# MySQL removing Duplicate Rows with Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have a table that has a the following columns:

```
ID(primary key),
USER,
ACTION
TIME
LOCATION
```

I am trying to *remove duplicate entries* using the columns: `USER, ACTION, TIME, LOCATION` together.

I wrote the following query :

```
DELETE FROM test.testlogins  
WHERE id IN (SELECT * 
             FROM (SELECT id FROM test.testlogins 
                   GROUP BY USER, ACTION, TIME, LOCATION HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
                  ) AS A
            );
```

However, when I execute it I am only getting 1 row deleted per run. My test data has approximately 40+ rows that are duplicates each assigned a separate `id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM
  testlogins t1 INNER JOIN testlogins t2
  ON t1.user=t2.user
     AND t1.action=t2.action
     AND t1.time=t2.time
     AND t2.location=t2.location
     AND t1.id>t2.id
```

you can use `t1.id>t2.id` if you want to keep the row with the minimum ID or `t1.id<t2.id` if you want to keep the one with the maximum.

Comment: This works as intended(deleted multiple duplicates) but I also was going to try using it as a trigger to keep the same from happening when duplicates are being added. Any thoughts on how to keep duplicates from being added.

Comment: @silverzpeed you should create a UNIQUE INDEX with `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_userlogins ON testlogins  (USER, ACTION, TIME, LOCATION)`

Comment: I have script at a remove server that builds a insert script and executes the insert. Will the error output i see in my logs effect the insert if there are duplicates.

Comment: @silverzpeed please see my other answer. yes if there's a unique index you will get an error when inserting duplicates... you could use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE ...` syntax to just ignore the duplicated insert without raising an error

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is adding a Unique  index to the table using `ALTER IGNORE`. This will avoid the issue in future, if the table size is not huge.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE testlogins ADD UNIQUE KEY (USER, ACTION, TIME, LOCATION)
```

**OR**

Create a new table in some other database with new unique index and load all the data into new table with INSERT IGNORE

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write this query is:

```
DELETE tl
    FROM test.testlogins tl LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT MIN(id) as id
          FROM test.testlogins 
          GROUP BY USER, ACTION, TIME, LOCATION
         ) tokeep
         ON tl.id = tokeep.minid
    WHERE tokeep.id IS NULL;
```

Presumably, the reason you are only removing one id at a time is because the `group by` in your statement returns only one id -- and that is the one you are deleting.  If one combination of the columns appears 40 times, you are only deleting one id in this group per `delete`.

This method, on the other hand, finds the row to keep (arbitrarily the one with the smallest `id`).  Then, it deletes everything else.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM testlogins  
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
               FROM testlogins t2
               WHERE t2.USER = testlogins.USER
               AND t2.ACTION= testlogins.ACTION
               AND t2.TIME = testlogins.TIME 
               AND t2.LOCATION = testlogins.LOCATION 
               AND t2.ID > testlogins.ID
              )
```

Remove all the rows with same property and with a lower id of the max

Comment: This will not work in MySQL because the subquery cannot reference the table where rows are being deleted.